# What is the area of the shaded region of the rectangle?

Tags: recreational-mathematics

what will be the area of the shaded region of the following rectangle.
Where 2m*2 and 3m*2 are the areas of the enclosed triangles.
I'm trying to figure out any help.
thanks

[image]

Comment: Please include your thought on the problem. If not, I will say the answer is $5.5$.

Comment: What do the "2" and "3" mean?  Are those the areas of the enclosed triangles?

Comment: @bob.sacamento  Yeah 2m*2 and 3m*2 are areas of enclosed triangles.

Comment: @EclipseSun could u plz share how u get 5.5

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1**

> It is enough to find the area of half the rectangle.

**Hint 2**

> Let the top, right and bottom triangles have areas $x,y,z$ respectively. Can you figure out the ratio $y:z$ based on the ratio $x:y$?

Comment: So is it 2/3=3/z, z=4.5. So half of the rect area is 7.5. So area of shaded one 5.5

Comment: @jquery404: Perfect. Next time, include your thoughts on the question, so that we can know where you are stuck and give you more appropriate help. =)

Comment: can u explain a little bit how $y:z$ can be compared with $x:y$.. i mean how it works

Comment: @jquery404: Didn't you get it just now? Well area of a triangle is half base times height, so if you choose the appropriate base you can see that $x:y$ tells you the ratio of two line segments, and then using the parallel lines and similar triangles you know the ratio of another two line segments, and then you know $y:z$.